# How to use exec with parameter to interact with running process being extracted

Tags: inno-setup

Salve!  Well, I have scoured the web (and Stack Overflow) for an answer.  I need help getting my Inno installer to send a commandline with parameters to a running application.

In myapplication_setup.exe I have packed myapplication.exe.  Now, myapplication.exe is equipped with the ability to receive commandline parameters.  If I launch a second instance with certain parameters, it will pass them to the first instance and then exit its own second instance (both are exited).  This lets me use the second instance of myapplication.exe to make the first instance exit.  This part works perfectly if I do it from a batch file or cmd box or run box.

Now, I need the installer to call this commandline:  "c:\myapplication\myapplication.exe quit" and then check to see if both instances have exited.  I might be able to get away with just checking for the second instance that the installer has launched, because they both exit at about the same time.  I don't know inno so well, so here is the code I have come up with to do the commandline function.  Problem is that I always get the ResultCode of 267 and myapplication has never exited.

The setup program needs to call the exec function and make sure myapplication.exe has exited before it extracts the new version of myapplication.exe.

Could someone look over my code and help me out?  Thanks!

```
[code]
function PrepareToInstall(var NeedsRestart: Boolean): String;
var
  ResultCode:   Integer;
begin
   if Exec('C:\myapplication\myapplication.exe', 'quit', '{app}', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
   begin
      msgbox('True: C:\myapplication\myapplication.exe : ' + IntToStr(ResultCode), mbInformation, MB_OK);
   end
   else begin
      msgbox('False: C:\myapplication\myapplication.exe : ' + IntToStr(ResultCode), mbInformation, MB_OK);
      SysErrorMessage(ResultCode)
   end;
end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears the 267 is an "invalid directory" error.
Are you sure the Exec is pointing to the proper location?
Personally, I would change your code to the following :

```
[code]
function PrepareToInstall(var NeedsRestart: Boolean): String;
var
  ResultCode:   Integer;
begin
   if Exec(ExpandConstant('{app}\myapplication.exe'), 'quit', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
   begin
      msgbox('True: C:\myapplication\myapplication.exe : ' + IntToStr(ResultCode), mbInformation, MB_OK);
   end
   else begin
      msgbox('False: C:\myapplication\myapplication.exe : ' + SysErrorMessage(ResultCode), mbInformation, MB_OK);      
   end;
end;
```

This of course assumes that the existing myapplication.exe is in {app} as well.  To be sure, you can always extract the myapplication.exe to the temp directory and run it from there.  Something like:

```
[code]
function PrepareToInstall(var NeedsRestart: Boolean): String;
var
  ResultCode:   Integer;
begin
   ExtractTemporaryFile('myapplication.exe'); 
   if Exec(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\myapplication.exe'), 'quit', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
   begin
      msgbox('True: myapplication.exe : ' + IntToStr(ResultCode), mbInformation, MB_OK);
   end
   else begin
      msgbox('False: myapplication.exe : ' + SysErrorMessage(ResultCode), mbInformation, MB_OK);      
   end;
end;
```

Comment: Well, I never thought of running myapplication.exe from another directory.  Thanks to the app's mutex, that part works.  However, I still can't get exec to run myapplication.exe, it keeps saying the directory is invalid.  Now, I am installing under a standard windows user account, so I have no admin rights in the installation location.  Maybe {tmp} is off limits?  I can create a temp directory, but I can't figure out how to extract to it.

Comment: When I use the {tmp} directory, the Exec function gives me the Result Code "C:\Users\BobUser\AppData\Local\Temp\is-N9JS3.tmp\myapplication.exe: The system cannot find the file specified.  Could this be a .net error, since my app is a .net windows forms application?

Comment: Your app might be missing some dependency.  What happens if you open Explorer and navigate to the directory listed while the message is on the screen?  Is the EXE there?

Comment: @ mirtheil Hmm... I didn't think of that. doh! It does have dependencies, which is why I was trying to run it from {app} in the first place.  But, no, the temp folder is-N9JS3.tmp doesn't even exist, which means the ExtractTemporaryFile didn't work either.

Comment: @ mirtheil Hey!  I got exec to answer true!  I gave up on the temp idea and just extracted to {app} anyway.  What my code was missing was the ExpandConstant bit, and I removed the working directory.  You have an extra parenthesis, however in your exec line.  It should be: Exec(ExpandConstant('{app}\myapplication.exe'), 'quit', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode).  Thanks alot!  I'll mark your answer!

Comment: Actually, I think I know what's happening.  Where in your install is this procedure being called?  If it's in InitializeSetup or InitializeWizard, the {app} value hasn't been set yet. I'm changing my code above.

Comment: Right in the PrepareToInstall procedure, like in my original post.  No, I was just using {app} before within code block; but that won't work there, it seems, but when I change it with the ExpandConstant function, it does work.

Answer (score 3):

From the Inno Help...

"Do not include quotes in the Filename parameter; the function will add them automatically."

This one caught me out, too.  I created an installer that calls the installer of a 3rd-party product.  It worked fine.  But the uninstaller had to look in the registry for the UninstallString of the 3rd-party product.  The string in the registry contains quotes, so when I passed it to Exec, it failed with error code 267.

The solution was to call:
  RemoveQuotes(uninstallString);

Comment: They aren't passing quoted file names to `Exec()`.